# How to handle `node(s) had taint` error in eks cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I deployed a K8S cluster on AWS EKS but when I deploy a pod to the cluster, the pod's status is `pending`. and I see below message when describe the pod. How can I solve the issue? I have tried to delete and redeploy the pod but keep getting the same error.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sidecar-app-59dd47fbdf-pjrfq   0/1     Pending   0          62s
Joey-Zeller:k8s joey$ kubectl get pods
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sidecar-app-59dd47fbdf-pjrfq   0/1     Pending   0          2m26s
Joey-Zeller:k8s joey$ kubectl describe pod sidecar-app-59dd47fbdf-pjrfq
Name:           sidecar-app-59dd47fbdf-pjrfq
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         name=sidecar-app
                pod-template-hash=59dd47fbdf
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/sidecar-app-59dd47fbdf
Containers:
  nginx:
    Image:        nginx:latest
    Port:         8080/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/nginx/nginx.conf from nginx-conf (ro,path="nginx.conf")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4dxhl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  nginx-conf:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      nginx-conf
    Optional:  false
  default-token-4dxhl:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4dxhl
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  75s (x3 over 2m31s)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

I see below error when I describe the node:

```
$ kubectl describe node ip-192-168-44-226.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Name:               ip-192-168-44-226.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name=elk
                    alpha.eksctl.io/instance-id=i-00dcf85feec486f1e
                    alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name=ng-32b00a62
                    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.medium
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-2
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-2b
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-192-168-44-226.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node-lifecycle=on-demand
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.medium
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-2
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-2b
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 19 Feb 2021 09:41:13 +1100
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  ip-192-168-44-226.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:51:15 +1100
Conditions:
  Type             Status    LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason              Message
  ----             ------    -----------------                 ------------------                ------              -------
  MemoryPressure   Unknown   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:50:05 +1100   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:52:04 +1100   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  DiskPressure     Unknown   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:50:05 +1100   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:52:04 +1100   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  PIDPressure      Unknown   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:50:05 +1100   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:52:04 +1100   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  Ready            Unknown   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:50:05 +1100   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:52:04 +1100   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   192.168.44.226
  ExternalIP:   3.26.77.215
  Hostname:     ip-192-168-44-226.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  InternalDNS:  ip-192-168-44-226.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  ExternalDNS:  ec2-3-26-77-215.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         2
  ephemeral-storage:           83873772Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      3977864Ki
  pods:                        17
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         1930m
  ephemeral-storage:           76224326324
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      3422856Ki
  pods:                        17
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 ec27cd0668c882d838f572a1981b762f
  System UUID:                EC27CD06-68C8-82D8-38F5-72A1981B762F
  Boot ID:                    6d26c69a-69ee-4a64-9cd4-48a289ec7d62
  Kernel Version:             4.14.214-160.339.amzn2.x86_64
  OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.6
  Kubelet Version:            v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
ProviderID:                   aws:///ap-southeast-2b/i-00dcf85feec486f1e
Non-terminated Pods:          (9 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                             CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                             ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  cert-manager                cert-manager-649c5f88bc-mfx67                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         29h
  cert-manager                cert-manager-cainjector-9747d56-9xlvv            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         29h
  cert-manager                cert-manager-webhook-849c7b574f-kg6hr            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         29h
  kube-system                 aws-load-balancer-controller-64dbfb945b-pjg88    100m (5%)     200m (10%)  200Mi (5%)       500Mi (14%)    44h
  kube-system                 aws-load-balancer-controller-64dbfb945b-q9hsh    100m (5%)     200m (10%)  200Mi (5%)       500Mi (14%)    29h
  kube-system                 aws-node-mctgj                                   10m (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         13d
  kube-system                 coredns-67997b9dbd-4vrxq                         100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (2%)        170Mi (5%)     29h
  kube-system                 coredns-67997b9dbd-7zgn9                         100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (2%)        170Mi (5%)     29h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-rbjrx                                 100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         13d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests     Limits
  --------                    --------     ------
  cpu                         510m (26%)   400m (20%)
  memory                      540Mi (16%)  1340Mi (40%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)       0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)       0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)       0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0            0
Events:                       <none>
```

it says `overcommitted.` error. Then I can see many pods are created in `kube-system` and `cert-manager`:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                                            READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
cert-manager   cert-manager-649c5f88bc-b25gt                   1/1     Terminating   9          34h
cert-manager   cert-manager-649c5f88bc-mfx67                   1/1     Running       0          29h
cert-manager   cert-manager-cainjector-9747d56-9xlvv           1/1     Running       0          29h
cert-manager   cert-manager-cainjector-9747d56-p7pxl           1/1     Terminating   17         34h
cert-manager   cert-manager-webhook-849c7b574f-kg6hr           1/1     Running       9          29h
cert-manager   cert-manager-webhook-849c7b574f-nhjxd           1/1     Terminating   12         34h
default        sidecar-app-59dd47fbdf-pjrfq                    0/1     Pending       0          13m
kube-system    aws-load-balancer-controller-64dbfb945b-ccd5d   1/1     Terminating   13         34h
kube-system    aws-load-balancer-controller-64dbfb945b-pjg88   0/1     Terminating   5          44h
kube-system    aws-load-balancer-controller-64dbfb945b-q9hsh   1/1     Running       2          29h
kube-system    aws-load-balancer-controller-64dbfb945b-ww65p   1/1     Terminating   1          7d
kube-system    aws-node-mctgj                                  1/1     Running       0          13d
kube-system    aws-node-prcps                                  1/1     Running       0          13d
kube-system    coredns-67997b9dbd-4vrxq                        1/1     Running       1          29h
kube-system    coredns-67997b9dbd-7zgn9                        1/1     Running       1          29h
kube-system    coredns-67997b9dbd-gjfqc                        1/1     Terminating   1          34h
kube-system    coredns-67997b9dbd-q9t7l                        1/1     Terminating   1          34h
kube-system    kube-proxy-l9mrq                                1/1     Running       0          13d
kube-system    kube-proxy-rbjrx                                1/1     Running       0          13d
```

They are created when I deploy the EKS cluster via `eksctl create cluster` command and `cert-manager` and `cert-manager` are created by them. I don't know what are useful and what not. Should I delete all of them? or how can I recreate them after deleting?

Comment: A pod can be scheduled on a node which has `Taints` only if there is a matching `Tolerations` on the pod. You can read about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/).

Comment: the taint `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable` looks like the node is not in a good state. try to check the status of the node using `kubectl describe node <nodename>`.

Comment: whatis output for `kubectl get nodes` , there are 2 nodes that are not available in your cluster

Comment: you are right, node is not ready and I put more info in this question. But how should I handle the issue in nodes?

Comment: I think the problem is the small node size and you probably need a larger node. I would imagine `2 cpu` to be pretty small for a node. I also see several other pods in `Terminating` state so if you describe them, you would probably get the cause as `OOM` or `cpu` limits.

Comment: I think this issue is caused by too many pods on kube-system and cert-manager namespace. The question is whether I can delete them or redeploy them?

Comment: Please refer to the docs [Unknown status to Ready status](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-node-status-ready/)  especially Check the status of the kubelet and [Nodes Management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/). Provide more information `kubectl get nodes`. Eventually [Resize your cluster](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-worker-node-actions/)

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as community answer, please edit this post and share with your findings about this issue:

Looking into pod description:

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  75s (x3 over 2m31s)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

and node description:

```
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
.
.
.

Conditions:
  Type             Status    LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason              Message
  ----             ------    -----------------                 ------------------                ------              -------
  MemoryPressure   Unknown   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:50:05 +1100   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:52:04 +1100   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  DiskPressure     Unknown   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:50:05 +1100   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:52:04 +1100   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  PIDPressure      Unknown   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:50:05 +1100   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:52:04 +1100   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  Ready            Unknown   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:50:05 +1100   Wed, 03 Mar 2021 18:52:04 +1100   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
Addresses:
```

It looks like there is problem with node or network connection. Kubelet stopped posting his status and the node has been marked with the taint:

```
node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
```

Please take a look at your console, check your kubelet status node status to find out more details.
use:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
kubectl get nodes -o wide
sudo systemctl status kubelet
sudo journalctl -u kubelet
```

**Note**:

> If the Status of the Ready condition remains Unknown or False for longer than the pod-eviction-timeout (an argument passed to the kube-controller-manager), all the Pods on the node are scheduled for deletion by the node controller. The default eviction timeout duration is five minutes. In some cases when the node is unreachable, the API server is unable to communicate with the kubelet on the node. The decision to delete the pods cannot be communicated to the kubelet until communication with the API server is re-established. In the meantime, the pods that are scheduled for deletion may continue to run on the partitioned node.

Additional information:

- [AWS NotReady or Unknown status to Ready status](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-node-status-ready/)
- [Kubernetes Node conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#condition)